# Is it possible to use wordpress theme on typo3 server?

Tags: wordpress, typo3

I am a newbie to wordpress and recently created a website using typo3 for a project at university (as my university servers are configured with typo3). I created the template using Templavoila and twitter bootstrap. I now have to use wordpress theme-HUGE as it is more interesting and suggested by the project partners. I have no idea if wordpress theme could be used on typo3 machine. If yes, how much overhead might occur? Could anyone provide some information on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress themes files can't directly be used in TYPO3.

I would suggest you create a new TYPO3 template using the template engine of your choice and then rebuild  the HTML structure of the Wordpress template. If your resulting HTML is exactly the same as for the Wordpress theme, you can use the included CSS and images.

Comment: You're writting two different statements ;) Of course that using WP themes IS possible, anyway as you also pointed - most probably it's requires some changes. BTW, by theme I just understand HTML+CSS+gfx;)

Comment: You're right - it's about how you understand the definition of "theme". AFAIK do Wordpress themes mainly consist of php-files, which contain a mix of HTML and PHP code. Those themes can't be used in TYPO3 directly, but with knowledge of HTML/CSS you can for sure rebuild every WP theme as a TYPO3 template.

Comment: Yes a Wordpress theme is not just HTML, CSS and graphics. A theme commonly includes PHP code and Javascript, together with admin pages. It's also tightly coupled with the Wordpress loop, and the way it structures HTML - and so CSS reflects that. Template files are divided up in ways that make sense for Wordpress, and would not necessarily elsewhere. They include action hooks, headers/footers, widget areas etc. that don't make sense outside of Wordpress, and a lot of the classes and HTML structures tend to come from Wordpress. You can rework it, but it's just like reworking any site's style.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the easy way, use wordpress for the wordpress theme.
As said above, moving the css from wordpress to TYPO3 is not that hard. But you can not easily move the functionality of a wordpress theme to TYPO3. You have to rebuild it in TYPO3. And that will make a big difference.

For example:
Assume you have to set up a slider element, which is included in the theme. When you use the theme in wordpress, you just need to activate it in the settings.

In TYPO3 you will have to build a custom element, either by building an own extension or using one of the common custom element extensions like DCE oder FLUX. (Don't use TemplaVoila anymore, it's outdated).

And a slider is a easy task compared to the case, that your partners say "hey, we forget the nice blog we have in our theme, let's activate it!". 
This might take you 2 clicks in the theme settings in wordpress, but if you want to port that feature to TYPO3 you should really know something about programming TYPO3 Extensions with extbase and fluid.

It might be a great project for learning TYPO3. But if it is a real project, with a real deadline, you will have a much more fun with it, when you use the wordpress theme in the way that it was meant to be used.